# Extend an HDF5 dataset in a negative direction

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I have a decently large 2D dataset (approx. 1000rows x 500000 columns) in an HDF5 file. The dataset was created so it is infinity extensible so I can easily add new rows to the bottom and new columns to the right.  However, occasionally I need to add new columns to the left hand side ... and that is where I am stuck.  Is it possible to extend an existing data set in this way.  The only way I know how to do it now is basically load all of the data and completely rewrite the file.  However, this seems very inefficient. FYI, I am using Matlab 2012a and the low level HDF5 commands Sample section of existing creation and column adding code below.

Basically I want to extend this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

To This without having to load all or rewrite the entire file.

```
NaN 1 2 3
NaN 4 5 6
NaN 7 8 9
```

Example code snipit of creation code with passed in data:

```
case 'create'
        data = varargin{1};
        % ---------- Data Info ----------
        dims = fliplr(size(data));  %flip due to H5 indexing order
        % ---------- Create Initial HDF5 File ----------
        fileID = H5F.create(filename, 'H5F_ACC_TRUNC', 'H5P_DEFAULT', 'H5P_DEFAULT');
        % Create dataspace with unlimited dimensions.
        datatypeID = H5T.copy('H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
        maxdims = {'H5S_UNLIMITED', 'H5S_UNLIMITED'};
        spaceID = H5S.create_simple (2, dims, maxdims);
        % ---------- Create the dataset property list, add gzip, set chunk
        chunk = [1024 1];
        propID = H5P.create('H5P_DATASET_CREATE');
        H5P.set_deflate(propID, 5);
        H5P.set_chunk(propID, chunk);
        H5P.set_fill_value(propID,datatypeID,NaN); %Fill with NaNs on creation
        % ---------- Create the compressed unlimited dataset.
        datasetID = H5D.create(fileID, dataName,datatypeID, spaceID, propID);
        % ---------- Write the data to the dataset.
        H5D.write(datasetID, datatypeID,'H5S_ALL', 'H5S_ALL','H5P_DEFAULT', data);
        % ---------- Close
        H5P.close(propID);
        H5D.close(datasetID);
        H5S.close(spaceID);
        H5F.close(fileID);
```

Example of adding a column to the right ... can it be added to the left instead?

```
case 'addColumns'
        c2Add = varargin{1}; %# of columns to add
        prevH5Info = h5info(filename);
        newdims(1) = prevH5Info.Datasets.Dataspace.Size(1);
        newdims(2) = prevH5Info.Datasets.Dataspace.Size(2)+c2Add;
        newdims = fliplr(newdims); %flip due to H5 indexing order
        fileID = H5F.open(filename, 'H5F_ACC_RDWR', 'H5P_DEFAULT');
        datasetID = H5D.open(fileID, dataName);
        % ---------- Get Data Space and Extend Existing Dimensions
        H5D.extend(datasetID, newdims);
        % ---------- Close
        H5D.close(datasetID);
        H5F.close(fileID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible even with the low level HDF5 commands.

The only solution is the expensive one: extend the end of the dataset, move the existing content, then add your new data at the beginning.

Hopefully you said “occasionally” so performance might not be such an issue…

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was afraid that this was going to be the answer.  Yes, it should be infrequent but I was hoping to avoid it if possible.  The only other solution I could think of was to the append the new "left side" columns to the right side anyway but keep some kind of tracking array that contained the correct order. So after the append my trackin array would look like [2 3 4 1] meaning the last column was really the first ... however this could get ugly after multiple appends.  Thanks anyway!